# WPF DataBinding with RelativeSource problem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am trying to create a view that holds a ListBox that its ItemsSource property is bound to an ObservableCollection and its ItemTemplate property is bound to another property. I know it is unclear, so I will add some code...

This code is the relevant section from my markup:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding FirstName}" Height="{Binding Path=Index, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

('FirstName' is a property of Person type, which is the type parameter of my collection. I wont add the code for that class because it is very intuitive)
The code-behind of the view sets the DataContext to hold a reference to and instance of this ViewModel class:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int index;
    ObservableCollection<Person> myCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> MyCollection
    {
        get 
        {
            if (myCollection == null)
            {
                //create the collection - not relevant for my question
            }
            return myCollection;
        }
    }
    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            //calculate value...
        }
        set
        {
            //set the value...
        }
    }
```

Since I bind the ItemsSource to the collection, I find it hard to bind to properties in my ViewModel (I manage to bind simply Person's properties...), and my code gives me binding error in the output window:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='SimpleMVVM.MainWindowViewModel', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Index; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

Can someone please help me figure that out?
(btw - sorry for the poor title, I just couldnt find anything clearer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Index property will be located in the `ListBox` DataContext so change the Height Binding to the following and it should work

```
Height="{Binding Path=DataContext.Index,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>
```

**For the ListBox**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding FirstName}"
                    Height="{Binding Path=DataContext.Index,
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>  
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. And yep - you are right, it works that way. Still I find it difficult to understand why: under the assumption that the Index property is located in the ListBox DataContext, that makes sense. But why? shouldnt it be located in the Window DataContext??? thanks again :)

Comment: @ET: It depends, if you set the DataContext for the `Window`, it will get set for the `Window` and then it will be inherited by the `Window` s Child unless that Child set its DataContext some other way. If that Child is a `Panel`, e.g. `Grid`, then all the Children of the `Grid` will also inherit the same DataContext. So the DataContext will be inherited all the way down to the `ListBox` that binds to the `MyCollection` property of the DataContext. All `ListBoxItem` containers will have an instance of the type for the Collection as the DataContext. Hopefully that answered your question :)

Comment: ok. After your clarification and short investigation I noticed that the DataContext property is a dependency property, and therefore it has value inheritance. Now its all clear. Thanks again, for your answer (and patience...) :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the DataContext of the height binding to the viewmodel the way it is now it is looking for the index property on the individual data items in the collection